Запятая перед "и даже"

Доступность: можно выйти во двор, и даже иногда мяч не обязателен,
если очень хочется поиграть.

Нужна ли запятая перед и в данном случае?

Правильно:
Доступность: (1) можно выйти во двор, и (2) даже иногда мяч не обязателен, (3) если очень хочется поиграть.
Пояснение
Бессоюзная связь не может повлиять на постановку запятой перед союзом И, так как союз связывает простое предложение и СПП. Предложения (1) и (2) семантически неоднородны.
